# Gradient background not getting in screenshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, html2canvas, canvg

I have a d3 chart in my application and what I want is to take a screenshot of the chart. I am using html2canvas.js and canvg.js plugin to convert the div content to base64 string. I used inline styles for plotting the chart. I got this solution from another post.

I have rectangles in my chart and I used gradient color to fill the rectangles but when I take a screenshot the background color of rectangles are not be displayed, see images below ↓↓. After searching some solutions I understand the html2canvas plugin has some limitations and canvg will also have problems with some designs.

```
var sContainer = $("#idtrendChartMain")
    svgElements = $(sContainer).find('svg');
    var savedSlideName;

    //replace all svgs with a temp canvas
    svgElements.each(function () {

        var canvas, xml;
        // canvg doesn't cope very well with em font sizes so find the calculated size in pixels and replace it in the element.
        $.each($(this).find('[style*=em]'), function (index, el) {
            $(this).css('font-size', getStyle(el, 'font-size'));
        });
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        sContainer[0].appendChild(canvas);

        //convert SVG into a XML string
        xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);

        // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
        xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');
        //console.log(xml);
        //xml = xml.replace(/xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/1999\/xlink\"/, '');
        xml = xml.replace(/xlink:/g, '');

        //draw the SVG onto a canvas
        canvg(canvas, xml);

        $(canvas).insertAfter(this);
        //hide the SVG element
        $(this).attr('class', 'tempHide');
        $(this).hide();
    });

    html2canvas($(sContainer), {
        allowTaint: true,
        letterRendering: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
            base64 = base64.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
            //creating the request
            var request = {};
            request.Base64 = base64;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: AQ.Verizon.Url + "/Home/StoreImage",
                //async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ request: request }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Data) {      

                },
                error: function (e) {

                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
            $(sContainer).find('canvas').remove();
            $('svg').show();
        }
    });
```

original chart
[image]

screenshot
[image]

Can I solve this problem with what I have got or is any a better plugin for taking the screenshot. Because if I use bellow code I  will not get exact screenshot of the screen and also the clarity is poor.